# mportError: No module named trunk.pife.pife.settings en Django

Tags: django

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django, el cual es directamente importado desde un Subversion, una vez instalados todos los requerimientos que se me exigen compilo el proyecto pero me sale estos errores. ¿Alguien que sepa como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, resulta que hubo un problema de enlace del proyecto con el entorno virtual.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que activar tu actual aplicación. Por la estructura que tienes, debieras descomentar la línea 40, es decir, tienes que tener activo el pifeapp.

Comment: Acabo de probar a descomentarlo, pero el error sigue apareciendo....

Comment: ¿puedes "subir" el modulo? Es decir, que quede arriba de ucaplantillas.